# Android studio, connection with loginactivity and mainactivity failing

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am trying to implement a logging in system in a Tetris code so that players can log in before they play. I've already made the database and it functions correctly. My problem arises when I try to call for LoginActivity.java on the MainActivity. Directly below is the portion of the MainActivity that calls for the LoginActivity(which is the next code box, and LoginActivity2 is shown in the last code). What happens is that when I run the code, it loads the Login page, I enter the username and password, registers the user, and when I try to log in, it redirects me to another login page which I made for registration. It never actually redirects into the game, it's on a forever stuck loop of logging in. I'm not sure exactly if i've wrote the intent calls wrong or something else. I just can't seem to get this to work correctly.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish(); // Optional gej bodjiin
        } else {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //There may be an error at R. I imported something weird from the suggestions
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        DB = new DBHelper(this);

        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String user = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                if (user.equals("")||pass.equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Enter all",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                else {
                    Boolean checkuser = DB.checkusername(user);
                    if(checkuser==false){
                        Boolean insert = DB.insertData(user,pass);
                        if(insert==true){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"User exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View view){
                                          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity2.class);
                                          startActivity(intent);
                                      }
                                  }
        );

    }
}
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit1);
    DB = new DBHelper(this);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(user.equals("")||pass.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity2.this,"Empty field",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                Boolean checkuserpass = DB.checkusernamepassword(user,pass);
                if(checkuserpass==true){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity2.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    loginUser();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity2.this,"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried to add functions to MainActivity and LoginActivity respectively to see if it will redirect at all. In the LoginActivity for when insert==true it should automatically redirect back to the MainActivity but the issue persists. I've also tried just trying to always set the code block below to true with the :

private boolean isLoggedIn() {

return true;

to which them my android emulator stops responding altogether whilst on the login page upon pressing log in.

```
if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish(); // Optional gej bodjiin
        } else {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: If i understood correctly what you are trying to do then i recommend you to use Android Navigation component you can see it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started. it will fix all the dependencies between your activities.

Comment: @EliP how do you think the navigation component is going to help over different activities ? these aren't fragments

Comment: As far as i know Android best practice instead of creating multiple activities you create one main activity and using fragments to render the views you need, In this way, the performance is beater because instead of redrawing the entire screen, it only draws the specific part, this way you solve two problems at once: performance improvement and let Android do the "heavy" lifting for you of managing the screens.

Comment: By the way you can also navigate between activities [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/migrate#combine)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way might be to add another screen, maybe something like a splash screen.
Then do the `isLogged` check on this screen and redirect the user to the respective screen. Below is a rough idea:

`Splash Screen`

```
// check if the user is logged in
// if not loggedIn, launch an intent to the login screen
// if loggedIn, launch an intent to the MainActivity screen
```

`Login Screen`

```
// after successful login, launch an intent to MainActivity and finish LoginActivity
```

There should be no Intent in the MainActivity.